# Why do some posts show up in more than one review queue? Could we stop it?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, review-tools

I have seen some posts show up on more than one category of the review panel.

For example, say a new user posts a one-line answer to an old question. This will flag the post for the Late Answers and Low Quality Posts review queues (and maybe also First Posts). I might then deal with it as part of sorting the Late Answers queue, and *also* as part of the Low Quality Posts one.

While I understand and support that these posts get put on all relevant queues, I find it a bit weird and slightly annoying to be asked to deal with the same post more than once. (It doesn't help that such posts are usually annoying and/or hard to deal with.)

Is this by design or can it be avoided? i.e. could posts I've already taken action on be removed from my review queues?

(I'm aware that this may be more suited to the mother meta, and [it has come up already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153406/posts-come-up-in-multiple-review-queues) with no answers, hence my asking here.)

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with asking about this here, but if it's already come up on MSO, anyone who is in a position to do anything about it will have already seen it there. So there's nothing to be gained by asking here as well.

Comment: It does seem to have fizzled, though. I don't suppose there's any way to bump this up over there? I imagine the bigger traffic in SO makes the review queues longer (or just more people look at them) so this is less of a problem there.

Comment: Upvote it. The dev team tends to prioritize highly upvoted feature requests; or at least, those with few votes get little attention from the team. It doesn't matter so much whether the question is active.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168169/add-a-reminder-for-same-review-item-on-multiple-queues Not all queues expect you to do all actions (f.e. you can't vote in the LQ queue, but you don't have  the autocomment in the Late Answers queue. However, if a post is reviewed in FP, it probably should be removed from LA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. You should no longer see the same post in the First Posts, Late Answers, and Low Quality review queues.

It's still possible to come across the same post in the other queues though. For example, you might see something in Suggested Edits, and then later in the Reopen queue.

Comment: I do . I see the same post in First posts and Late Answers many times .